# POSIX Headers (from MinGW project) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013, mingw, posix

*(Continues from: [Porting from Code::Blocks to Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621522/porting-from-codeblocks-to-visual-studio-2010/27621811#27621811) - I'll remove this if it's against StackExchange's formatting rules)*

I'm trying to port an open source *Code::Blocks* project, which originally uses **MinGW** and **GCC TDM-1 4.7.2** (does not support newer versions), to *Visual Studio 2013* (NOTE: I switched from 2010 to 2013 for the question above). The code uses 1998 ISO C++ standard and uses various additional utilities like *SDL2*, *OpenGL*, *Zlib*, *Lua*, and others.

The main problem is, the project includes some libraries which VS does not have;
so I wanted to ask if anybody knows if these are Unix-only libraries, libraries from a utility included in the project which I overlooked or libraries my VS installation is for whatever reason lacking, and mainly if they can be fixed, replaced with VS equivalents or downloaded from somewhere without massively porting/editing the code itself first.

In particular, at the current build attempt (I have not scanned through all of the project source files to look for other errors) the missing libraries are:

- **unistd.h**(*)
- **cpuid.h**
- **sys/time.h**

---

(*)*EDIT*: I've looked a bit around and I found **unistd.h** can be *possibly* replaced with io.h or with a custom subset of the original Unix library, so I'll also try these options.

---

*EDIT2*: Apparently, they're all Unix (POSIX) libraries which, from what I understand, are fundamentally incompatible with the *MSVC* compiler, even if forcefully included into the project.

I've also tried to set the Visual Studio project to use MinGW as a custom compiler, but not only I can't get it to work properly, I've read that VS can not parse debug information from *GCC*-compiled binaries, which is one of the two major reasons I wanted to port to VS in the first place.

I've also read about this plugin called [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/mingw/); does anybody know about it? Does it make possible for VS to compile and debug MinGW programs?

Comment: It seems that you are getting into too much trouble. Basically, gcc follows POSIX while MSVC follows MS ;) I know that MS API has its own system information and timing routines which is rarely similar to POSIX. MinGW has created such ports. In any case could you list the missing routines? I mean remove unsupported includes and list unresolved functions.

Comment: I tried removing some of them, but I'm having another major issue: the project contains GNU-compatible, modified versions of OpenAL, Freetype2 and Lua (some parts of it are POSIX, some aren't), which I don't really want to mess with.
I think I'd rather try out VisualGDB at this point, or stick with C::B for full compatibility.

Comment: Also, Merry Christmas from Italy everyone! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I tried the ***VisualGDB*** extension and it pretty much solves all the issues. MSVC and MinGW hate the crap out of each other and I really couldn't do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar problem with the time related headers. This was my solution.

[This repository](https://code.google.com/p/madp-win/source/browse/src/include/sys/times.h?r=4ef496e2071896b295262c89eb36a8b3d7656bae) provided an implementation of those time related functions. They also appear to have an automatically exported github project with the same files, in case that original repository link stops working: https://github.com/zhouheng/madp-win/tree/master/src/include/sys

I took their three files: time.h, times.h and times.cpp, dropped them into a folder called "sys/" within my project directory, and then replaced all references to:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

to use:

```
#include "sys/time.h"
```

for local file reference. So far I have not encountered any problems. Please note this is not my code and the original license(s) of the code is LGPL.